# How to login in Fantasy Premier League using python

Tags: python, api, jupyter-notebook, rest

How can I get authenticated information of fantasy premier league website. I am getting authentication failure.

```
import requests 
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth 
import aiohttp
import asyncio

session = requests.Session()


data = {
     "login" : "email", 
     "password" : "pass", 
     "app" : "plfpl-web", 
     "redirect_uri" : "https://fantasy.premierleague.com"
}


url = "https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login/"
r = session.post(url, data=data)
print(r.status_code) # 200

url = ('https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/my-team/{teamId}/')
r = requests.get(url)
json = r.json()
json.keys() # json object details says "Authentication credentials were not provided".
```

Comment: you are not sending any Authorization token in the header. `requests.get(url, headers = {'Authorization': *your token*})`

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you maintain the cookies from the login call to the 'teams' call. Specifically, there's a cookie named `pl_profile` which serves for authentication.

Here's a piece of code that does the trick:

```
s = requests.Session()

headers = {
   'authority': 'users.premierleague.com' ,
   'cache-control': 'max-age=0' ,
   'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1' ,
   'origin': 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com' ,
   'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ,
   'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36' ,
   'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' ,
   'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site' ,
   'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate' ,
   'sec-fetch-user': '?1' ,
   'sec-fetch-dest': 'document' ,
   'referer': 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/my-team' ,
   'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,he;q=0.8' ,
}

data = {
    "login": "abc@def", 
    "password": "123456", 
    "app": "plfpl-web", 
    "redirect_uri": "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/"
}

url = "https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login/"

res = s.post(url, data = data,  headers = headers)

team_url = "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/my-team/1234567/"
res = s.get(team_url)
json.loads(res.content)
```

The output is:

```
{'picks': [{'element': 123,
   'position': 1,
   'selling_price': 12,
   'multiplier': 1,
   'purchase_price': 13,
   ...
```

Comment: not the clubs. I was talking about personal team that is associated with email/account.

Comment: Updated the answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi,I tried this code for connecting to get my team on FPL API, but after few successful attempts, suddenly I got this error : {'detail': 'Authentication credentials were not provided.'}
I'm new on using FPL API.